# JWplayer Timesliderprossbar not working

Tags: jwplayer

I am working on Java(spring) and try to implement Jwplayer for online streaming ( every thing is working fine While I am using static file( file:upload/bunny_vod.m3u8,) I am facing problem while data comes from server(file: "../packager/m3u8?sessionId=" + sessionid + "&subscriberId=" + subscriberId,) time Slider progress bar is not working properly please let me know how can I get rid off this problem?

please see the link for jwplayer code.Here commented part of file source not working and uncommented part is working
http://pastie.org/7990343

Comment: Do you have a link to where the player is actually embedded?

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.I am new in spring and Jwplayer.Actually when i give Uncommented file source its timesliderprogress bar working fine but when i give commented file source then video is playing but Time Slider progress bar is not working it always showing 00.00.The commented url given in the file, by this url m3u8 playlist being generating through .ts file within multiple .m3u8 file.Please see the full code here http://pastie.org/7990801#

Comment: I have already seen the code. I want to see a link so I can actually debug it properly. Please provide that if possible, thanks.